# Issues signing with ISCmdBld? Error 6259

Tags: installshield, signing

I have a Basic MSI project that I can successfully build and sign on my local system through the InstallShield 2015 interface (running as admin). The whole process only takes a minute or 2.

However, if I proxy into our build system to use ISCmdBld to build the exact same project, it fails just after logging the line:
 `Started signing certificate.msi ...`

The specific error logged is:
`ISDEV : error -6259: Internal build error`

The command line I used for ISCmdBld is (not as admin):

```
ISCmdBld.exe -p "W:\MyProject\Setup\Project Setup.ism" -x
```

In both cases, the .ism file to be built is the exact same project file. But when running this command through the build system, it seems to hang up on a lot of lines similar to `Started signing SomeExeMyProjectUses.exe...`. While InstallShield finishes these lines within a second or 2, ISCmdBld hangs on them for over 20 seconds before continuing (except for certificate.msi where it fails completely. This means that ISCmdBld takes minutes to error, where running through the interface succeeds in half that time.

The build system is not connected to the internet, in case that matters, although I can successfully build other projects that are not signed.

Comment: You can get more log lines, sometimes around an error, by adding `-v` to the iscmdbld.exe command line. Does that help differentiate? I'll check what we can tell from a -6259 when I'm in the office.

Comment: @MichaelUrman - No luck with `-v`. It just shows the same failure and logs the deleting of some temp stuff, but that's it.

Comment: The most likely culprit appears to be MsiGetFileSignatureInformation returning an unexpected error code. Is this any call to iscmdbld, or just ones hosted in an unusual context (e.g. by a service or scheduled task running as system)?

Comment: @MichaelUrman - Any call I have done. The way we currently call it is manually via a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I just fix that bug on our build server, the problem was that the Certification chain were not trusted. (internal certificate for developpment)

make sure the CA certificate and The intermediate certificate are installed on the machine.

also the signing process usually require the access to an external timestamping authority.